# Unable to reach remote server when running Android app via Trigger.io

Tags: android, android-manifest, trigger.io, remote-server

I am trying to deploy a web app to android via Trigger.io. Although the app manages to load initially, I was unable to access the remote server via the app. I received an error while trying to login via the remote server (seen below)

I am using the following code to submit the username and password value to the remote server

```
$.post "#{window.Public.domain}/users/login",
   nickname: $('input.username').val()
   password: $('input.password').val()
```

[image]

[image]

I deployed the same app to IOS and it ran ok i.e. accessing the same remote server was not an issue

Anyone has an idea why I am unable to access the remote server on the android environment whereas I have no issues on the IOS environment?

Attaching the manifest for reference

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="io.trigger.forge9b9f8cdedc7f11e2bd4912313d00dc45" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1374544692" android:versionName="0.1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Fulfilled" android:name="io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp">
    <activity android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|fontScale|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity" android:stateNotNeeded="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider android:authorities="io.trigger.forge9b9f8cdedc7f11e2bd4912313d00dc45" android:exported="true" android:name="io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeContentProvider" tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider" />
</application>
```

UPDATE:

Tried the suggestion from James to change from using $.post to forge.request.

Now when I tried to call the server, I get this error back

[WARNING] java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 - Connection refused
[WARNING]   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
[WARNING]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:62)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)

The domain I specified in my app for the server post is as such

```
forge.request.ajax
  url: "http://localhost:9000/users/login.json"
  type: "POST"
  data:
    nickname: $('input.username').val()
    password: $('input.password').val()
```

The above works for the IOS deployment. Is there any other config I need to take care of?

Comment: How is that form being submitted? There are cross-domain security restrictions to think about, because your app is running on a different scheme and domain to the remote server...

Comment: @JamesBrady I am using a $.post to submit the username and password values. I have updated the OP with the code used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-domain XHR requests are not possible without extra configuration from a Trigger.io app.

In this case, you should be able to use `forge.request.ajax` to submit the form: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/request.html.

In other cases, where usage of the request module is impossible, it may be possible to set up `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers on the server side so that normal XHR works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out. I didn't think of trying that out because it worked for the IOS deployment.

Comment: Hi, I tried that out on the android emulator and I am getting an error. I have updated the OP with the error. It will be great if you can help take a look.